# How to change the color of UIToolBar, when the system theme changes?

Tags: ios, swift

I set the UIToolBar.appearance().tintColor in .onAppearance. However, I am not able to change the color of the bottomBar when the default theme changes to dark or to light. My question is how am I able to change it, here is my code:

```
.onAppear {
            if colorScheme == .light {
                UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(self.backgroundColorBottom)
            } else {
                toolBackground = UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 40/255, blue: 42/255, alpha: 100/100)
            }
}
       .onChange(of: colorScheme, perform: { _ in
            if colorScheme == .dark {
          UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 40/255, blue: 42/255, alpha: 1/100)
            } else {
                UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(self.backgroundColorBottom)
            }
        })
```

So, if I run the app - the colors are correct. But, when I go to background and change the theme. The bottom UIToolBar's color is not changing. Is there anyway to change it?

Comment: Can you show about more, and perhaps a [mre]? I made a toolbar in a `UIViewRepresentable` and it automatically updates the theme without manual changes.

Comment: @George It is changing to the default colors - Black and White. But I want to change it to the custom colors. I am not able to change it to the custom colors. I don't have enough reputation to add images. Otherwise, I would.

Comment: @George I actually solved my problem making the toolbar completely transparent, and having another view behind it, which changes its color.

Comment: You can self-answer your question, which will help future readers more easily find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the UIToolBar completely transparent. So, it will have the color whatever the view is behind.

I created an extension to the UIToolBar

```
extension UIToolbar {
    func setBackgroundColor(image: UIImage) {
        setBackgroundImage(image, forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    }
}
```

and then, created an Image with the solid clear color.

```
.onAppear {
   UIToolbar.appearance().setBackgroundColor(image: UIImage(color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 34))!)
}
```

Comment: And if you don't want to change all `UIToolbar` styles globally, have a look at [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).